# Android build error Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, build.gradle, android-build

**App Building error:'app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'** I know by deleting one class can resolve this error but I don't know how to delete it
or is there any other method to resolve this.

thanks

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules
> jetified-firebase-iid-21.0.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.0.1) and
> jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
> Go to the documentation to learn how to d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors
> Fix dependency resolution errors

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 28s
18 actionable tasks: 18 executed

This is my module gradle File

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shipelse"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            //useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.5.0'

    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0"

    // For Identity Credential APIs
    implementation "androidx.security:security-identity-credential:1.0.0-alpha02"
}
```

This is my project gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.mapmyindia.com/repository/mapmyindia/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a mix of Firebase dependencies, some relying on the BOM for versions, others with versions specified directly in the `dependencies` closure. That seems inconsistent and it may be contributing to your problem. Have you tried removing the version numbers from `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging`, to be more like how you have `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have both mavenCentral and jcenter as repositories. Remove jcenter() from your project gradle file since it is already obsolete.

Also, remove the version of you firebase-messaging dependency:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

Answer (score 3):

Enable androidX and Jetifier in gradle.properties file. Add the following lines to the gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
```